# How to integrate leanpay payment method in magento 2?

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.4.3.p1

I am working on leanpay payment integration in magento 2. I have this doc link : https://docs.leanpay.com/developer-portal/slo-docs/plugins/magento/magento-2/

I have downloaded the module and configured it correctly but its not working as expected. There no much information available on web.

Anyone have any idea about how to integrate leanpay correctly ?

Thanks in advance.